# Heroku Scheduler: Will it spin up a new dyno if a worker already exists?

Tags: heroku, scheduler, dyno

I have a worker dyno used by Sidekiq to process background jobs and sits idle most of the time. If I schedule a task with the Heroku Scheduler, would that task use this running worker dyno or will it spin a new one?

Do I have control over this?

Comment: I re-read the documentation. It always spins up a dyno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-read the documentation. It always spins up a dyno.